# How could you make a fire appear a different color with medieval tech?

Tags: medieval, fire

A street performer in the medieval age could make some money. One popular performer is a fire eater. Changing the color of his flames would likely make his popularity rise so that he would make more money.

Is it possible to change the color of a flame?

Comment: This is the exact basis of atomic emission spectroscopy...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_emission_spectroscopy

Comment: I just hope he has enough money to buy the materials to change the colour of the flames. Also its probably not the greatest idea to eat the poisonous fire, eat the normal one and do other tricks with the different coloured flames.

Comment: or just don't use poisonous ones

Comment: This is also how the colors of fireworks are produced. Fireworks in general were invented in ~7th century CE China; I don't know exactly how old _colored_ fireworks are, but knowing that certain substances burn colorfully is totally plausible for "medieval".

Comment: You ought to wait at least 24 hours before “accepting” an answer here on WB.  Also, please don’t change the question once it has been answered!  Finally, would you *please* type your capital letters and punctuation marks?!  All of your questions have been “fixed” by others to appear normal.

Comment: In the process of entertaining people try to not get burned for witchery.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**You can't get black**

While it is possible to achieve different ranges of colours depending on *temperature* of the flame as well as *combustible material*, fire's still *light*.

*Light* is bound to the spectrum of *visible* wavelengths. And there is **no *visible* wavelength for black**.

*Addition<sup>1</sup>*: It is important to understand that the light of fire is [additive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_color). Hence if you'd want to go towards *black* fire, you'd actually have to find a way to remove light-sources from a) the fire itself and b) its surroundings; thus creating a space that absorbs light.

---

**But what colours of fire can we have?**

Looking at [pyrotechnics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrotechnic_colorant) we can achieve the following colours by e.g. burning different [metal salts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(chemistry)):

[image: Chart of metal ions and flame colours]
<sub>Chart of what substance creates which flame colour - found on [http://www.compoundchem.com](http://www.compoundchem.com/2014/02/06/metal-ion-flame-test-colours-chart/)</sub>

---

These colours are achieved, as already stated, by burning salts. As long as we know where to find metals, we can dig them up and refine most of them with as little tools as [a vat of acid and some patience](http://www.bbc.co.uk/education/guides/zptrd2p/revision).

The most accessible of these would probably be:

- Lithium
- Potassium
- Calcium
- Copper
- Iron
- Lead
- Zinc

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Thank you [Slipp D. Thompson](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8879/slipp-d-thompson)</sub>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59720/discussion-on-answer-by-dot-sp0t-how-could-you-make-a-fire-appear-a-different-co).

Comment: Adding onto the “You can't get black” explanation, it's important to understand that fire's light is additive with the light coming from behind it _(with some refraction and other effects)_.  So when you achieve black fire, it just appears clear.  To get fire that _appears_ black, you'd need it to not only produce no light, but also block the light of the surrounding environment that would pass through it.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson would you feel comfortable with me adding your explanation (or an abbreviated version) to the answer body?

Comment: Absolutely.  All yours.

Comment: Oh, there is a wavelength for black: light that is outside the visual spectrum, or at a wavelength that appears negligibly bright against a stronger light source - for example, alcohol fires can be nigh invisible in bright conditions (happens in car racing, driver's on fire and everyone wonders why he's so agitated...). Add black smoke and you have black...

Comment: "These colours are achieved, as already stated, by burning metals" - no! Re-read you quote, it talks about "metal salts", and they're pretty accessible. Burn table salt, and the flames will be yellow, since it's sodium chloride.

Comment: Sodium shouldn't be hard to come by either. It exists in ordinary table salt (and is kind of required to live: there's a reason why "salary" is what we are paid: back in Roman times a man was paid in *salt* hence why its called a salary). Although I don't know if table salt really changes the color of the flame: its already yellow.

Comment: Would achieving the right heat level be a problem with medieval tech?

Comment: @MiloP you'd literally sprinkle a fine powder into an open flame. This works with really any open flame.

Comment: As Joker_vD says, you do _not_ need these elements in metallic form to achieve the effect. In particular calcium and potassium _salts_ are indeed easy to find, The problem however, in a medieval setting, is to get a clean enough setting. A sooty pitch torch isn't hot enough to get the metal ions to a great luminosity; the little purple or green you may get from your potassium or copper will be hardly noticeable beside the light of the torch itself or sodium impurities (sodium is basically everywhere, is particularly effective at flame-lighting, but with an uninteresting orange colour).

Comment: Lithium is a bit hard to obtain. It's fairly reactive. Arsenic and Antimony are easier (known to Romans, for instance). Baryte (Barium) has also been around for a while, being known to the Han Chinese (it's used to make Han blue, so it was known as a pigment).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from metal ions as mentioned above, it has to do a lot with flame TEMPERATURE. There is a reason behind the term "color temperature" - the cooler the more reddish (eventually crossing into invisible near-IR), the hotter the more blueish (eventually crossing into invisible ultraviolet. That's why the sun is creating so much UV that we are glad the athmosphere filters it, that's why really hot light sources like arc lamps or halogen incandescents are best enjoyed with UV filters).
Actually that behaviour is not specific to flames, any material that is heated will behave that way (so called blackbody radiation) - flames are made out of gas....

Comment: It isn't blackbody radiation that makes some flames appear blue (no normal flames are hot enough to shift the color that far).

Comment: The dust of some metals can get surprisingly hot when burning...

Comment: Not that hot. Not anywhere *near* that hot. Making a flame distinctly blue (as opposed to blue-tinted white) would require temperatures of close to 10000 K.